# Confusion about Lighthouse report of unused JS for react devtools chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, lighthouse, react-devtools

When I run Lighthouse for the project I am working on, I get

```
chrome-extension://fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi/build/react_devtools_backend.js
```

as no1 causer of unused JS.

How is that making sense from a performance optimization perspective?
I can't control what extensions the user runs in his browser.
I also can't find anything about the React dev tools in the project.

Would highly appreciate if someone could shed some light on that issue.

[image: lighthouse report sample]

Comment: can you try disabling react devtools extension in the chrome before running the lighthouse analysis?

Comment: @neerajjain I tried that and it indeed disappears from the list. still the question remains why this appears at all, since from what I understand it should list things that I, as a developer, can influence.

Comment: when your pages load this addon will also automatically loaded on the page. this is the simplest explanation.

Answer (score 14):

I found the issue is because the file of the devTools is installed when the page is loading... and it is useless in production mode.
So go to the extension and right click on it.
Then go to the manage extensions.
Then find the "Allow this extension to read and change all your data on websites you visit" change it to "on click".

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. Just disable the React_dev_tools in chrome extension.